# Order root by name, and their images by position with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm making an app withe react, graphql, apollo and mongoose, and I'd like order my data by name (in this case there is no problem), and their own set of images, by position. I've something like this (in pseudo-json):

```
{data: 
  {
  name: "Name 3"
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 3.22"
      position: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.91"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.73"
    }
  },{
{
  name: "Name 2"
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 2.53"
      position: 3
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.61"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.32"
      position: 2
    }
  }
```

The result must be:

```
{data:
  {
  name: "Name 2",
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 2.61"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.32"
      position: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Image 2.53"
      position: 3
    }]
  },{
  name: "Name 3"
  Images:[
    {
      name: "Image 3.91"
      position: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.22"
      position: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Image 3.73"
    }]
  }
}
```

I use `return ArticleModel.find(filtro).limit(20).sort({name: "asc", "Images.position": "desc"}).select(projection).exec();` but it is wrong. In case that position is `null` or doesn't exist, then it should be at the end of the list of images.
Any ideas??

Comment: Your images are inside an array. Are you sure `Images.position` works as expected?

Comment: With asp It worked xD. I want to move an old project to this new tecnology. A had tables "articles", "images" and "articles_images", where each article had a set of images with position....so in mongoose, after moving all information, I'd had something like that. An Article has an array of images (objects refered to another collection "Images"), but with some extra information such as position, when it was added or modified.... I can't use `position` in the Image, because  really it's an object, and it could be used by another article too.  Is it what you want to mean about your question?

Comment: you have to `$unwind` the images array in order to `$sort` it